# Change Serilog Sink based on Current Dependency Injection Scope

Tags: .net, logging, blazor, blazor-server-side, serilog

I want to send logs to different API endpoints based on the user that has logged in.

**Background**

Each user must supply their Username, Password and Server when logging in. There are scoped dependency registrations in my Blazor Server WebApp that will configure an ApiClient. The ApiClient will remember it's credentials for the duration of the Blazor Circuit.

```
services.AddScoped<IApiClient, ApiClient>();

...

interface IApiClient
{
  bool Authenticated { get; }
  void Authenticate(Credentials credentials);
  void Log(LogEvent logEvent)
  ...
}
```

Across my application I use the Microsoft's logging interfaces either injecting the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger with `@inject ILogger<MyComponent>` or via constructor injection.

I want my implementation of `ILogEventSink` to change based on the current DI Scope.

**Suggestion**

Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
public class MySink : ILogEventSink
{
  public MySink(IApiClient apiClient)
  {
    this.apiClient = apiClient;
  }
  
  public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
  {
    if (apiClient.Authenticated)
      apiClient.Log(logEvent);
  }
}
```

I don't believe Serilog or Microsoft support this as `MySink` is instantiated just once at startup and saved in a local variable rather than being instantiated when it's needed.

Is there a way to achieve this whilst still using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

The answer lied in creating a scoped service accessor that just saves the scoped `IServiceProvider` in a static `AsyncLocal` that can then be obtained by a custom `Sink`. It's a similar approach to how the `IHttpContextAccessor` works.

**Part 1**

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#access-server-side-blazor-services-from-a-different-di-scope for information on creating the Scoped Service Accessor in Blazor and making it available for every interaction.

The key parts were this,

```
public class CustomComponentBase : ComponentBase, IHandleEvent, IHandleAfterRender
{
    [Inject]
    private IServiceProvider Services { get; set; } = default!;

    [Inject]
    private BlazorServiceAccessor BlazorServiceAccessor { get; set; } = default!;

    ...

    private async Task InvokeWithBlazorServiceContext(Func<Task> func)
    {
        try
        {
            BlazorServiceAccessor.Services = Services;
            await func();
        }
        finally
        {
            BlazorServiceAccessor.Services = null;
        }
    }
}
```

and this in `_Imports.razor`,

```
@inherits CustomComponentBase
```

**Part 2**

The custom sink looks like this,

```
public class CustomSink : ILogEventSink
{
    private readonly BlazorServiceAccessor scopedServicesAccessor;

    public CustomSink(BlazorServiceAccessor scopedServicesAccessor) 
    {
        this.scopedServicesAccessor = scopedServicesAccessor;
    }

    public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        var scopedApiClientService = scopedServicesAccessor.Services.GetService<IApiClient>();
        // Perform scoped Serilog logging operations here ...
    }
}
```

And the Serilog registrations look like this,

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<BlazorServiceAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IApiClient>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CustomSink>();

...

builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) => configuration
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.Sink(services.GetRequiredService<CustomSink>())
);
```

Note: You can get in a mess if your scoped services used in the Sink themselves do logging so be careful not to... stackoverflow.